# Hbase / Hadoop Query Help

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I'm working on a project with a friend that will utilize Hbase to store it's data.  Are there any good query examples?  I seem to be writing a ton of Java code to iterate through lists of RowResult's when, in SQL land, I could write a simple query.  Am I missing something?  Or is Hbase missing something?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you, like many of us, are making the mistake of treating bigtable and HBase like just another RDBMS when it's actually a column-oriented storage model meant for efficiently storing and retrieving large sets of sparse data. This means storing, ideally, many-to-one relationships within a single row, for example. Your queries should return very few rows but contain (potentially) many datapoints.

Perhaps if you told us more about what you were trying to store, we could help you design your schema to match the bigtable/HBase way of doing things.

For a good rundown of what HBase does differently than a "traditional" RDBMS, check out this awesome article: [Matching Impedance: When to use HBase](http://blog.csdn.net/arthurbryant/article/details/6643933) by Bryan Duxbury.

Comment: The Duxbury link is broken, but I ouldn't find it elsewhere. :-\

Comment: Mirror of Duxbury article: http://blog.csdn.net/arthurbryant/article/details/6643933 (available as of Feb 2014)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access HBase using a query language and a JDBC driver it is possible. Paul Ambrose has released a library called HBQL at hbql.com that will help you do this.  I've used it for a couple of projects and it works well.  You obviously won't have access to full SQL, but it does make it a little easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at Hadoop and Hbase and as **Sean** said, I soon realised it didn't give me what I actually wanted, which was a clustered JDBC compliant database.

I think you could be better off using something like [C-JDBC](http://c-jdbc.objectweb.org/) or [HA-JDBC](http://ha-jdbc.sourceforge.net/) which seem more like what I was was after.  (Personally, I haven't got farther with either of these other than reading the documentation so I can't tell which of them is any good, if any.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend taking a look at Apache [Hive](http://hive.apache.org/) project, which is similar to HBase (in the sense that it's a distributed database) which implements a SQL-esque language.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply Sean, and sorry for my late response.  I often make the mistake of treating HBase like a RDBMS.  So often in fact that I've had to re-write code because of it!  It's such a hard thing to unlearn.

Right now we have only 4 tables.  Which, in this case, is very few considering my background.  I was just hoping to use *some* RDBMS functionality while mostly sticking to the column-oriented storage model.

Answer (score 0):

Glad to hear you guys are using HBase! I'm not an expert by any stretch of the imagination, but here are a couple of things that might help.

- HBase is based on / inspired by BigTable, which happens to be exposed by AppEngine as their db api, so [browsing their docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/creatinggettinganddeletingdata.html) should help a great deal if you're working on a webapp.
- If you're not working on a webapp, the kind of iterating you're describing is usually handled with via map/reduce (don't emit the values you don't want). Skipping over values using iterators virtually guarantees your application will have bottlenecks with HBase-sized data sets. If you find you're still thinking in SQL, check out cloudera's pig tutorial and hive tutorial.
- Basically the whole HBase/SQL mental difference (for non-webapps) boils down to "Send the computation to the data, don't send the data to the computation" -- if you keep that in mind while you're coding you'll do fine :-)

Regards,

David